# C++ OpenEcs Components dynamically

Tags: c++, templates, entityx

For those not familiar OpenEcs, it works much like the EntityX library.

- https://github.com/Gronis/OpenEcs
- https://github.com/alecthomas/entityx

---

I'm using OpenEcs library and I need do this kind of thing to create an entity with components:

```
entities.create_with<Velocity, Position>();
```

The template used in this method is:

```
template<typename ...Components>
```

Well, what I want to do is build this `<Velocity, Position>` dynamically, like this:

```
vector<size_t> components = {1, 2};
auto& componentList = // something

for (auto& component : components)
{
  switch (component)
  {
    case 1:
      componentList.add(Velocity);
      break;

    case 2:
      componentList.add(Position);
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}

entities.create_with<componentList>();
```

---

PS: I can do separately too, for example

```
entity.add<Velocity>();
```

But, for performance gains, the first way is better, how can I do to work like the first way?